# Zend Server CE extremely slow page loads for select sites

Tags: php, apache, zend-server-ce

I have a bunch of sites set up on my local development environment. Out of those sites I have two sites where I experience horribly slow page load times. Horribly slow, like approximately 5 minutes. The thing is my computer (mac pro osx 10.6, dual xeon nehalem processors, 6 gb of ddr3 memory) is adequately equipped and the other sites load real quick. I know its not a programming issue because the slow sites are fast on their production servers. Also these sites are just straight up PHP and MySQL stuff, no advanced frameworks or anything. These sites are configured the same way as all the other quick sites on my local machine and the same as what I've done on other dev environments where i haven't experienced the same issue, same version of Zend Server CE, PHP, and OSX. This problem is severely affecting my productivity working on these sites. I sincerely hope you guys have some input :-D

Comment: Any idea of what is causing the slowness? Db connection? Serving files? Should be easy to narrow it down a little bit.

Comment: Have you used a profiler / Firebug's "Net" tab to try and find at which point the long waiting period occurs?

Comment: Also you can check the zendserver logs to see if there is anything timeing out or reporting an error of some sort. And what happens after 5 minutes? is the webpage ok? Is there an error?

Comment: index.php is the longest load time, everything else is acceptable. 1:45 seconds for DNS lookup. I've got my hosts file configured correctly and index.php is only 22k.

index1.gif took 1:15 but its only 71 bytes. 

I've turned off all of the Zend components, tried with just the optimizer, now i'm trying optimizer and debugger.

Which profiler would you suggest?

Comment: after the long wait everything loads exactly as it should. This last time it only took 3:00

Comment: And the logs (apache, mysql slow query and php) show nothing abnormal.

Comment: @Bobby I feel like an idiot asking that but in that index.php file you are sure there is nothing that could loop for ever or wait on some service of anykind. I mean if you just put echo `hello world`; in index.php does it still take forever?

Comment: No, nothing like that. All of the files are exact copies of whats on the servers. Both production environments run as expected, its a local issue. 

What are your thoughts on the DNS lookup taking so long? It's a select few of the local files that are taking forever. I do have references to the live site for images and stuff but that stuff loads within milliseconds. Given it's only a few of the local files causing the problem I'm baffled.

Comment: And you know there's no such thing as a stupid question :-D I appreciate all of your guys help on resolving this so ask away, any and every thought on the solution to this is worth voicing.

Answer (score 2):

First, check to see if using a "standard" TLD makes a difference. Lots of developers use ".dev" or ".local" as TLD within their local environment. Sometimes these can lead to long timeouts. Switch to a standard TLD—pick any one that won't cause a conflict for you—and see if that helps.

If you're still having issues, note that OS X Lion may place DNS servers ahead of your local /etc/hosts file when resolving names! Try `scutil --dns` to see where `domain : local` appears in the sequence.

If "local" not #1 then see: http://www.justincarmony.com/blog/2011/07/27/mac-os-x-lion-etc-hosts-bugs-and-dns-resolution/ for resolution under the heading "Solution: DNSMasq". The solution given here—along with using a standard TLD worked well for me.

(I've also seen alternative solutions, *e.g.*, http://clintberry.com/2011/05/wildcard-sub-domains-on-osx-web-development-on-localhost/, but have not tested them.)

Comment: I was using a .local TLD that was resulting in a 5 seconds dns delay. Changing my vhost to a standard one fixed it for me. You just saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue, you have to add the ipv6 version also or it takes forever...

```
/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1     yoursite.local
::1           yoursite.local
```

The ::1 line will fix your issue!